# Request data arrives with fields defaulted in Controller Action

Tags: asp.net-web-api, binding, httprequest

I am sending an object through a `HTTP` `Post` request to a `ASP NET Web Api` controller and the object arrives with its fields defaulted:

**POCO**

```
[Serializeable]
public class A
{
 public int X{get;set;}
 public int Y{get;set;}
 public string Z{get;set;}
}
```

**Sender**

```
  var payload=JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new A() { X= 2, Y= 3,Z="aa" });
  HttpRequestMessage message = new HttpRequestMessage {
                    RequestUri = new Uri([somepath]),
                    Method = HttpMethod.Post,
                    Content=new StringContent(payload)
  };
  var resp = await this.client.SendAsync(message);
```

**Controller**

```
 [HttpPost]
 [Route([somepath])]
 public async Task<Catalog> GetCatalogRange(A request) {
     //A.X =0 , A.Y=0 ,A.Z=null
 }
```

I do not understand how can the binding go wrong .

Comment: You may need to add ([FromBody] A request)have you tried that?

Comment: Yes i have to no avail.

Comment: try the following to your string content, StringContent(payload, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

Comment: I have tried that too , still nothing unfortunately.